# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed when trying to download images with Alamofire

Tags: ios, google-maps, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am trying to download tile images to a GMSTileLayer from a url with SSL.

GMSTileLayer contains a delegate method that loads tiles into a google maps layer:

```
override func requestTileFor(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt, receiver: GMSTileReceiver) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(urlPrefix)x=\(x)&y=\(y)&z=\(zoom)&is2d=t")
    let zoom = UInt((self.map?.camera.zoom)!)

    Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in
        if let image = response.result.value {
            receiver.receiveTileWith(x: x, y: y, zoom: zoom, image: image)
        }
    }
}
```

When this function is called, I get the following error messages:

```
2017-06-22 09:55:49.192 PPGaugeApp[78556:4886424] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
2017-06-22 09:55:49.274328-0400 PPGaugeApp[78556:4886488] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]
```

I have verified that the urls are returning images by testing in a browser.

In researching this error, nearly all of the posts suggest making some changes to the plist to include at minumum the following:

```
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
```

My current plist settings are as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>someDomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Nothing in the plist seems to have any effect on this error message. Other classes in our app are using https for authentication without issue, however this is the only place we are downloading a file through an https url.

Is there any place else we should be checking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Due to some percentage Escaping character present in url string url conversation going wrong. use below string extension for getting url from string.

```
extension String {
    var getUrl: URL? {
        let strurl = (self as NSString).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        return URL(string: strurl)
     }
}
```